# How to get Azure App Service TLS configuration information using Azure .NET Fluent SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net, azure-fluent-api

I'm trying to get TLS version configured on an App Service (WebApp) using Azure Fluent .NET SDK in C#.

I used the following code to get WebApp information using LINQPad :

```cs
    // Nuget : Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent -Version 1.24.0
    // using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent;
    // using Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models;
    // using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;

    // Using a Service Principal created on my Azure Subscription
    var clientId = "<service_principal_clientid_with_readaccess>";
    var tenantId = "<my_azuread_tenantid>";

    var credentials = SdkContext
        .AzureCredentialsFactory
        .FromServicePrincipal(clientId, 
            Util.GetPassword("azure-cli-secret"), // LINQPad helper, replace if needed 
            tenantId, 
            AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

    // Get one web app with TLS 1.2 configured
    var webApp = AppServiceManager
        .Authenticate(credentials, "<azure_subscription_id>")
        .WebApps
        .GetById("<webapp_resource_id>");

    // Dump object returned, LINQPad helper method
    webApp.Dump();
```

When dumping object model returned, I don't find the TLS information returned anywhere. That something that should be available since it's returned by the REST API.

### Analysis

You can see that the information is available using https://resources.azure.com or directly on this endpoint :

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appServiceName}/config?api-version=2018-02-01
```

That give you the following output (properties list shortened here) :

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appServiceName}/config/web",
      "name": "{appServiceName}",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "location": "West Europe",
      "properties": {
        "http20Enabled": false,
        "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
        "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
        "reservedInstanceCount": 0,
        "preWarmedInstanceCount": null,
        "healthCheckPath": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "nextLink": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appServiceName}/config"
}
```

Then I looked at the SDK code source available here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net. I found that the TLS version should be available in the [SiteConfig](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/src/ResourceManagement/AppService/Generated/Models/SiteConfig.cs#L523) object. This **SiteConfig** appears to be located inside the **Inner** property.

When looking at the object dump we got with LINQPad, we can see that the SiteConfig object isn't populated :

[image]

When debugging this code, with a break point, we can see that the information seems available internally but it's not mapped to the **SiteConfig** property available publicly inside **Inner** property.

Debug session screenshot where we see the non-public member _siteConfig populated :

[image]

Is it a bug or I missed something ?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you use this way, the `siteConfig` will always return null. It is by design. If you want to get the related information, you can use the following method which would correct configuration as per your requirement:

```csharp
AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
            clientId,
            clientSecret,
            tenantId,
            AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud).WithDefaultSubscription(subscriptionId);

RestClient restClient = RestClient
            .Configure()
            .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .WithCredentials(credentials)
            .Build();

ResourceManagementClient resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(restClient);
WebSiteManagementClient webSiteManagementClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(restClient);
webSiteManagementClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
var configs = webSiteManagementClient.WebApps.GetConfigurationAsync("<rg name>", "<app name>").Result;
var minTls = configs.MinTlsVersion;
Console.WriteLine(minTls);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's working ! My original intent was to query all our subscription app services to get their TLS configurations, in one call (using ListAsync). I was entusiast that would be possible when I saw the object model returned, I was more skeptical when I saw that the Get call didn't returned the info either. I will have to query every app service config :(

Answer (score 1):

Once this PR gets merged, the property `MinTlsVersion` should be available on the `webApp` directly.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/pull/1023